# How to read Avro data and put the Avro fields into dataframe Columns using Spark Structured Streaming 2.1.1?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Code from the website

```
DataSet<Row> ds = sparkSession.readStream()
  .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
  .option("avroSchema", schema.toString)
  .load();
```

Since Avro Messages has fields. I am wondering how to put each field of the message in a separate column of a DataSet/Dataframe ? Does the above code automatically do that?

I